# how to save picture after do operation

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I use this code to save a picture using a `PictureBox`:

```
pbMainPicture.Image.Dispose();
string fBitmapName = storagePath;
pbMainPicture.Image = new Bitmap(fBitmapName + ".bmp");
Image img = Image.FromFile(fBitmapName + ".bmp");
img.Save(fBitmapName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
img.Dispose();
```

but I get this exception: `System.ArgumentException` was unhandled in this line of code:

```
pbMainPicture.Image = new Bitmap(fBitmapName + ".bmp");
```

Comment: Please post the full exception Message (excluding the stack).

Comment: `fBitmapName` is probably not valid. It might have an extension, or it might not be an existing file.

Comment: what is in storagePath? Are you sure it points to a valid file with a .bmp extension? are you doubling the .bmp extension using string concatenation?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx. Make sure you want to open a file by specifying a valid path (I suppose it can't be URI).

Comment: storagePath-->is a foldet to save image on it ,and it's code         storagePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\save-f\\";

      //if the storage directory doesn't exist we create it
      if (!Directory.Exists(storagePath))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(storagePath);

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the line generates the exception, then inspect the content of fBitmapName, you need to make sure fBitmapName + ".bmp" is a valid image file in your hard drive